# Snap causing Double commander to show fake drives

Tags: 16.04, snap, drive, doublecmd

anyone has idea how can I remove this Snap related fake drvies from double commander?

They are not present in Files 3.14

[image: s]

Here is output of **lsblk -f**

```
NAME   FSTYPE  LABEL UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
loop1  squashf                                            /snap/phpstorm/54
sdd                                                       
├─sdd2 ext4          1ba9d0a0-9832-403e-aeed-c4c4836edd18 
├─sdd3 swap          efd53592-0fd7-47bf-b52c-c0a285a1712f 
└─sdd1 vfat          D3F4-44C8                            
sdb                                                       
├─sdb2                                                    
└─sdb5 ntfs          B2E20D7A46C0E68B                     
loop4  squashf                                            /snap/phpstorm/57
loop2  squashf                                            /snap/core/5548
loop0  squashf                                            /snap/phpstorm/61
sdc    ext4    Data1 beb8660b-e698-4b5c-84cc-923ab4b97384 /media/aleksandar/Data
sda                                                       
├─sda2 ext4          37a7338d-efc9-4837-9e49-4dc88d463e44 /
├─sda3 swap          739d67c2-2f13-479f-8a6d-1fbbde716370 [SWAP]
└─sda1 vfat          61FF-05B5                            /boot/efi
loop5  squashf                                            /snap/core/5662
loop3  squashf                                            /snap/core/5742
```

and output of **losetup**

```
NAME       SIZELIMIT OFFSET AUTOCLEAR RO BACK-FILE
/dev/loop1         0      0         1  1 /var/lib/snapd/snaps/phpstorm_54.snap
/dev/loop4         0      0         1  1 /var/lib/snapd/snaps/phpstorm_57.snap
/dev/loop2         0      0         1  1 /var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_5548.snap
/dev/loop0         0      0         1  1 /var/lib/snapd/snaps/phpstorm_61.snap
/dev/loop5         0      0         1  1 /var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_5662.snap
/dev/loop3         0      0         1  1 /var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_5742.snap
```

Comment: Please add output of `lsblk -f` and `losetup` to the question.

Comment: @N0rbert added outputs

Comment: Your outputs confirms the preliminary idea - DoubleCommander show mount-points of snap-applications (you can find exact numbers 54, 57, 5548, 61, 5662, 5742 on the toolbar). What is interesting I have tested doublecmd (installed 0.8.2-1 from official APT repository) on 18.04 LTS and do not see snap drives here. But on 16.04 LTS I can confirm the behavior. I tried to add snap locations to *Ignore list* in *Options→Ignore list* with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that problem is fixed in modern versions of Double Commander.

For example version 0.8.2 from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS does not show snap mount-points.

But you can install newer version of Double Commander on 16.04 LTS from [the PPA](https://launchpad.net/~alexx2000/+archive/ubuntu/doublecmd):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alexx2000/doublecmd
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install doublecmd-gtk
```

and enjoy:

[image: DoubleCommander not showing snaps if installed from PPA on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS]

Comment: They are still visible for me in version 0.8.4 beta on Fedora 29. Any idea?